# Indicate the user that data is being loading

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to show a progress bar or anything else on the screen when a particular piece of code will execute. How can I do this?

Comment: this question has been asked before too many times just do some search please.

Comment: downVoted pehpaps because very basic thing . you should read docs before ask here .

Comment: No downvote. See the official docs at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-threads-and-progressdialog