# Displaying a progress dialog until new activity loads

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I have a progress dialog I am trying to show when a user clicks a button to launch a new activity. The spinner should be displayed on the current page until the other activity appears. ( The activity can take sometimes up to 4-5 seconds to launch and without the spinner it just shows a pressed button that looks frozen )

This is what I have, it's only working if I remove `hideProgressDialog();`, but then the spinner will still be there when I back to the previous activity, obviously.

What am I doing wrong ?

**Progress Dialog :**

```
    public void showProgressDialog(Context context) {
    if(this.progressDialog != null) {
        this.progressDialog.dismiss();
        this.progressDialog = null;
    }
    this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Chargement en cours, veuillez patienter");
}    

public void hideProgressDialog() {
    if(this.progressDialog != null) {
        this.progressDialog.dismiss();
        this.progressDialog = null;
    }
}
```

**Function :**

```
public void startActivity(Context context, Class<? extends Activity> activityClass) {
    try {
        showProgressDialog(context);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityClass);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);         
            startActivity(intent);    
            hideProgressDialog();
    }
    catch(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Example of a button click where this calls the function to show the spinner :**

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId() == R.id.changeBannerButton) {
        getBaseApplication().startActivity(this, BannerListActivity.class);
    }...
```

Comment: So... why does the activity take so long to start up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `hideProgressDialog()` in the `onResume()` method.  This way, if the user presses the back button, the `onResume()` method gets called and immediately hides the progress dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Well First off you should use the new DialogFragment class with FragmentManager. Because showdialog() is deprecated from API level 8

Next you should use **showdialog** and **removedialog** for adding and removing the dialog.

And you should use the **onCreateDialog** to handle the dialog and the operations. Like start a new thread to run do the job when you are displaying the progressdialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load data in a seperate thread on start of activity. But before start of that process show the progress dialog. Now once the process is done use runOnUI to hide the progress dialog..

[Indicate the user that data is being loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148221/indicate-the-user-that-data-is-being-loading/8148241#8148241)

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-threads-and-progressdialog

and this:

[Android - using runOnUiThread to do UI changes from a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901239/android-using-runonuithread-to-do-ui-changes-from-a-thread)